# Cannot get json response from http request

Tags: python, http, https, python-requests

I am trying to get a JSON response using the requests module. Was wondering if anyone knows what could be causing this.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/"

data = requests.get(url)

data.json()
```

Error:

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

> In case the JSON decoding fails, r.json() raises an exception. For
>   example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response
>   contains invalid JSON, attempting r.json() raises ValueError: No JSON
>   object could be decoded.

You need to have a `url` that could possibly return a `json`:

```
import requests

url = 'https://github.com/timeline.json'    
data = requests.get(url).json()    
print(data)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'message': 'Hello there, wayfaring stranger. If you’re reading this then you probably didn’t see our blog post a couple of years back announcing that this API would go away: http://git.io/17AROg Fear not, you should be able to get what you need from the shiny new Events API instead.', 'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The page you are returning is not json, its html